# Script mode in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am new to Python (and coding in general) and am reading Allen Downey's "Think Python, 2nd Edition" and Section 2.4 discusses the difference between *interactive mode* and *script mode*. I am using Jupyter Notebook as my interactive environment and am wondering how to switch between interactive and script mode. Do I need to save my code as a .py file to run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can but is not appropiate. Notebooks are not thinking as files for scripting mode else interacive, cases where you need to test more rapidly. But, if you insist, the answer is documented in [Jupyter Notebook docs](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html).